# Limit 60 requests by minute in for loop with node JS

Tags: node.js, for-loop, zoho

I'm working with zoho crm api, two make two api calls, one to get the ID and the other to update a record, the problem is that i have a 60 calls per minute.

I've an array with lots of info that I use to update the records.

Is there any way I can call 60 times per minute to avoid getting blocked? or any other work around?

```
var censados = [...] <-- big array
for (var i = 0; i < censados.length; i++) {

var elcorreo    = censados[i].email;
var elpais      = censados[i].country;

var criteria = "(Account Name:"+elcorreo+")"
var criteria = encodeURI(criteria);


var options = {
    hostname: 'crm.zoho.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/crm/private/json/Potentials/searchRecords?authtoken=apikey&scope=crmapi&newFormat=1&selectColumns=Potentials(POTENTIALID)&criteria=' + criteria,
    method: 'GET'
};

 https.request(options, function(response) {
        var responseData = '';
        response.setEncoding('utf8');

        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            responseData += chunk;
            jsonObject = JSON.parse(chunk);
        });

        response.once('error', function(err) {
            // Some error handling here, e.g.:
            res.serverError(err);
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            try {
                //console.log(responseData.response.result.Potentials.row.FL.content)
                console.log(jsonObject.response.result)

                if (jsonObject.response.result.Potentials.row.FL.content) {

                var IdPotential = jsonObject.response.result.Potentials.row.FL.content;

                // START UPDATER

                  var xmlData = '\
                    <Potentials>\
                        <row no="1">\
                            <FL val="País de Recidencia">'+elpais+'</FL>\
                        </row>\
                    </Potentials>';

                    var xmlData = encodeURI(xmlData);

                    var options = {
                        hostname: 'crm.zoho.com',
                        port: 443,
                        path: '/crm/private/xml/Potentials/updateRecords?authtoken=apikey&scope=crmapi&id='+IdPotential+'&xmlData='+xmlData,
                        method: 'POST'
                    };


                    https.request(options, function(response) {

                    response.setEncoding('utf8');

                    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                        responseData += chunk;
                        //jsonObject = JSON.parse(chunk);
                    });

                    response.once('error', function(err) {
                        // Some error handling here, e.g.:
                        res.serverError(err);
                    });

                    response.on('end', function() {
                        try {
                                console.log(responseData)
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log(e)
                        }

                    });
                }).end();


                };
                //END UPDATE


            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }

        });
    }).end();

}
```

Comment: maybe I'm totally wrong, but have you tried setInterval() ?

Comment: Take a look at this package https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter very handy for rate limiting!

Answer (score -1):

1. Seems that your code in not valid. You have to provide APIKEY for your account
   [Generate Auth Token](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/using-authentication-token.html#Generate_Auth_Token)
2. API calls limited on your account. As usual 250-500 requests /user depends on your subscription [API Limit](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/api-limits.html), so I suggest you use [mass update call](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/updaterecords.html#Update_with_Version4) (version = 4).

You can play with API using  [Zoho CRM Console](https://apigee.com/i.vatsenko/embed/console/zoho-crm)

Comment: I deleted the key intentionally, as you can see here https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/searchrecords.html  _You can trigger this method only 60 times per minute._, mass update is a good idea tought